# Bandwidth of an energy signal

Tags: bandwidth

I'm studying for my midterm , and I'm struggling with finding bandwidths.

I have this energy spectral density : $\Psi(f)= { 1  \over \sqrt {  1 +  ({f \over B }) ^2} }$ ,  and I need to find  the $3$ $dB$ band and the band with $90%$ % power.

About the $90%$ % case, do I need to find the total energy and then  $\int_0^W \Psi(f) = 0.9 \times  Total Energy$?

One think that doesn't make sense for me is that I'm dealing with an energy signal but I need to find something related to power.

If I had a power signal and wanted to find the 3 dB bandwidth, would I need to find the average power and then solve $\int_0^W S_x(f) = 0.5 \times TotalPower$ ?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for the bad english.

Comment: Are you sure that the energy spectral density is given as in your question *with* the square root in the denominator? Could it be that it is just the magnitude of the Fourier transform, i.e. $|X(f)|$ (and not $|X(f)|^2$ )? Then the whole problem would make much more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using the following assumption: the *magnitude* of the spectrum is given by the formula

$$|X(f)|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(f/B)^2}}$$

Then the energy spectral density is

$$|X(f)|^2=\frac{1}{1+(f/B)^2}\tag{1}$$

The 3 dB bandwidth is simply the frequency for which (1) becomes $0.5$, which is $W_{3dB}=B$. The bandwidth according to the 90% energy/power definition is

$$\int_{-W}^W|X(f)|^2df=0.9\cdot\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|X(f)|^2df\tag{2}$$

Equation (2) is the reason why I assume the definition as given in (1), because otherwise the integral on the right-hand side of (2) does not converge, so the 90% energy/power definition would not make sense. With the definition (1) the integrals in (2) are easily solved using the $\arctan$ function, from which $W=const\cdot B$ follows, where $const=6.31$ (if I'm not mistaken), but I'm sure you can do the calculation yourself.

Comment: You assumed correctly.  Thanks a lot. But the answer is that,  because the total energy is 1, right?

Comment: Another question about the dBs.  With energy / power spectral density everything works "smoothly", I mean,  3 dB means really 0.5, but why is that with amplitude, 3 dB means 1/sqrt (2) ?

Comment: @JoaoReis: The total energy is just the integral with infinite limits on the right-hand side of (2) (without the factor $0.9$). Its value doesn't matter, and here it is actually not equal to $1$. And the factor $1/\sqrt{2}$ appears with amplitudes because power/energy = amplitude$^2$.

Comment: Ok,  so why is the method for solving 3 dB (which is 50%) and 90% different? I mean isn't 3 dB a different way to express 50%?

Comment: @JoaoReis: It's a matter of convention. It explicitly says '90% power', so here you know for sure that they're talking about integrals. When talking about a 3dB cut-off frequency for filters, then one means the frequency at which a signal is attenuated by 3dB.